# How can I convert a list of hexadecimal strings to a single string with escape characters?

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, hex

I have a list:

```
list = ['0x01','0x02','0x03']
```

But I need to convert it to a string with form:

```
string = "\x01\x02\x03"
```

If someone could help me please, I'm really stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be a discussion going on regarding two different interpretations to your question.  Blender gave the answer for the exact question you asked, which produces the three character string `"\x01\x02\x03"`.  iCodez thinks you wanted the twelve character string `r"\x01\x02\x03"` and you seemed satisfied with that answer.  So can you please clarify whether you meant to have an `r` in your question or not, please, and if so, edit your question.  If not, please accept Blender's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int()` actually strips off the `0x` part if the radix is 16:

```
>>> int('0x01', 16)
1
```

So all you need to do is convert each element into an integer and pass it into `chr()`:

```
''.join([chr(int(c, 16)) for c in lst])
```

Comment: You would completely lose the hexadecimal part by doing this (I.E. the leading 'x'), and you didn't address the escape chars.

Comment: This should not have been downvoted.  It answers the question perfectly as asked.  It may be that the question was asked improperly (we don't know) but this answer gave the correct answer for the way the question was asked.

Comment: Yes it does.
`>>> lst = ['0x01','0x02','0x03'] 
>>> ''.join([chr(int(c, 16)) for c in lst])
'\x01\x02\x03'`

Comment: ah you're right, my bad, I didn't think it would return the slash, just tested it myself as well. I think the first answer is more clear though.

Comment: Also it depends on what the OP wants. Does he want the literal char `'\x01'` or the string `r'\x01'`

Comment: The two answers are completely different.  I have asked for clarification.

Comment: @aruisdante in Python `'\x01'` abd `"\x01"` are exactly the same thing.  The question is whether the OP wants `"\x01"` or `r"\x01"` (the latter can also be written `"\\x01"` of course).  But yeah, one character or four, that is the question.

Comment: that pesky `r` operator, I was blanking on how to express the difference between the two and so reverted to C++ annotation, bad habbit

Comment: @aruisdante: `'\x01' == "\x01" != '\\x01' == r'\x01'`